# Save and restore value

Tags: android

How to save and restore android app Int value

for example a simple counter save (counter value),  call new (counter value) on app restart.

do i have modify the manifest file to save int value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preferences:   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html